# How do you replace a line in a text file?

Tags: python

How would I replace a specific line in a text file with python?

TXT FILE (stock.txt):

```
ID      NAME
0341    Screws
0345    Nails
```

Code:

```
file = open("stock.txt")
string_to_replace = "0341    Rivets"
```

I have tried several methods including `fileinput`, but none of them seem to work.

```
import fileinput

file = open("stock.txt")
search = "0341"
for a in file:
    if search in a:
        searched_line = a

for line in fileinput.input(file, inplace = True):
    line.replace(searched_line, string_to_replace)
```

That returned an error:

`OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect`

I am probably missing something big, but does anyone else have any ideas?

Comment: Several problems: (1) first arg must be a file name, not an open file, (2) `inplace=True` only means the output ultimately replaces the original file, but you still need to write everything out, (3) `line.replace()` doesn't operate in-place, you have to capture the return value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is just because it can't find the directory/file, you must have the path/to/file wrong, but i think your code it's not the greatest as it is, you should do it like this to replace a line:

```
string_to_replace = "HEYA"
with open('tests.txt', 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()
    text = text.replace(string_to_replace, 'REPLACE BY MEE PLEASEEEE')

with open('tests.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(text)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure why you're getting the `OSError`, but here's code that doesn't encounter it and seems to do what you want (tested on Windows 7):

```
import fileinput

search = "0341"
string_to_replace = "0341    Rivets"

for line in fileinput.input("stock.txt", inplace=True):
    line = line.rstrip()
    if search in line:
        line = string_to_replace
    print(line)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. i didn't know that there is a built-in module in `Python` called `fileinput`.

Comment: @nexus66: You're welcome. It's a little tricky to use because it redirects `stdout` to the input file when `inplace=True` is used. Although I suspect it's not uto;ized all that much nowadays, it can do several other useful things besides what's illustrated here and makes writing Unix-like read from `stdin` and write to `stdout` type of utilities easier. Check out the [online documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html#module-fileinput).

Comment: i will check the link. Thanks a lot.